# Why was this -f flag returning true?

Tags: virtualhost, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, httpd.conf

I recently set up a rewrite to serve `.webp` files in place of `.jpg` files whenever possible. It seemed to be working correctly until today we noticed that a newly uploaded `.jpg` image was returning a `404` even though the image was present. I did some checking and found that the server was rewriting the `.jpg` URL to `.webp`, and then getting a `404` because the `.webp` hadn't been created yet.

I then moved the rule from vhost_ssl.conf over to .htaccess and did a bunch of tinkering until I found something that worked, then moved that solution back to vhost_ssl.conf. But I still don't understand why the original rewrite sometimes failed. Can anyone review and shed some light on the subject?

Original rewrite:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} image/webp
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1.webp -f
RewriteRule (.+)\.(?:jpe?g|png)$ $1.webp [NC,T=image/webp,E=webp,L]
```

Final rewrite:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} image/webp
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)\.(?:jpe?g|png)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1.webp -f
RewriteRule .* %1.webp [NC,T=image/webp,E=webp,L]
```

The only real difference between the two methods is that in the new method I check if the request URI matches jpeg/png before the rewrite condition that checks if the file exists. I think the new method is less efficient since the rewrite rule matches everything, but at least the condition above filters it, and it's in vhost_ssl.conf which is better than .htaccess.

Some other notes:

- During testing, I changed the original rewrite to a 301 redirect so I could see the file it thought it found. Sure enough, the file was the same as the .jpg file, just with a .webp extension - correct path and all (even though the .webp didn't really exist).
- Also during testing, I tried changing the rewrite condition to `RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1.webp_asdfasdfasf -f`just to verify that it would in fact fail, and it did. So it knew that the completely bogus file didn't exist, but it still thought the .webp file did exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr**

> ```
> RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1.webp -f
> ```

It should be `$1`, not `%1` in the `RewriteCond` *TestString*. Although it's unclear why this behaviour should have only recently changed (or maybe it hasn't?).

---

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} image/webp
> RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1.webp -f
> RewriteRule (.+)\.(?:jpe?g|png)$ $1.webp [NC,T=image/webp,E=webp,L]
> ```

This should *never* have worked, unless you had a file called "`.webp`" (with no *basename*, starting with a dot) in the document root. If you did, then it would have *always* rewritten the jpeg/png URL to `<whatever>.webp`, whether it existed or not.

So, this would seem to suggest you do have a file called `.webp` (no basename) in the document root? (And/or you are seeing a cached redirect for some requests? See below...)

The `%1` backreference in the 2nd `RewriteCond` *TestString* should be `$1`, not `%1`. `%1` is a backreference to the first captured group in the last matched *CondPattern* - of which there is none, so `%1` is *always* empty. So, it will *always* test the existence of `/path/to/document-root/.webp`. `$1` on the other hand is a backreference to the first captured group in the `RewriteRule` *pattern*, ie. the filesystem path/basename, excluding the file extension.

You have used `$1` in the `RewriteRule` *substitution* - you should have used the same in the preceding *condition*.

Note, that if these directives are in a Virtual Host context then you should either... remove the slash in the `RewriteCond` *TestString*, for example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} image/webp
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}$1.webp -f
RewriteRule (.+)\.(?:jpe?g|png)$ $1.webp [NC,T=image/webp,E=webp,L]
```

OR, exclude the slash in the `RewriteRule` captured group. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} image/webp
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.webp -f
RewriteRule ^/(.+)\.(?:jpe?g|png)$ /$1.webp [NC,T=image/webp,E=webp,L]
```

Otherwise, you'll end up with a double slash in the *TestString* that the OS will need to resolve.

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} image/webp
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)\.(?:jpe?g|png)$
> RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1.webp -f
> RewriteRule .* %1.webp [NC,T=image/webp,E=webp,L]
> ```

This achieves the same as simply using `$1` in the original rule block (as mentioned above). Curious that you changed the backreference in the *substitution* to `%1`, but knew to leave the backreference in the condition unchanged (or was this simply overlooked)?

> During testing, I changed the original rewrite to a 301 redirect ...

Always test with 302 (temporary) redirects. 301s are cached persistently by the browser, so can cause caching issues later. (In fact, this can account for "intermittent" behaviour when the request hits the browser cache.)

Comment: Crap!! I do have a `.webp` file in the directory root, probably resulting from an automated script that creates the `.webp` files accidentally creating this as well. About the `%1` backreference yesterday, I had the idea that `%1` is for rewrite condition and `$1` is for rules. I had the incorrect `%1` originally because I thought that since it was being used as part of a rewrite condition, it should be `%1`. I have it working now, thanks!